# Adjust volume of sound effect based on speed of collision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, box2d

I am using Cocos2D with Box2D to create a simple physics game. I want to adjust the volume of a collision sound effect depending on the speed of the colliding body. The faster the body is travelling when it collides, the louder the sound. I am using the SimpleAudioEngine library which has a playSound method with a gain parameter. Is there a way to convert the speed of the colliding body (a b2Body object) to a value between 0 and 1 that I can apply to the gain?

Answer (score 2):

In the post solve function get an impulse value, divide it by 100 perhaps? I'm not sure what the levels of impulse you get are.

```
void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse)

{
    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();

    void* userDataA = fixtureA->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    CCNode *myActorA = (CCNode*)userDataA;
    void* userDataB = fixtureB->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    CCNode *myActorB = (CCNode*)userDataB;

            // stuff above will allow you to work out which objects are hitting each other

            // get the impulse
        int impulseInt = impulse->normalImpulses[0];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bongeh. That looked like the perfect solution until I read that PostSolve is not called for sensors and one of the bodies in my collision happens to be a sensor. Maybe I could take the LinearVelocity of the body and use the vector length to convert that to a gain value? Just got to figure out how to translate the scale. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ah, i didnt realise you'd got a sensor, technically, as it's just a sensor for collision detection, no physics collision simulation gets called, so it has no impulse. I think your onto the right track there. Speed of the object hitting the sensor calculated against your own arbitrary fake simulation to give you a value.